# java QuickServer object handler

Tags: java, sockets, open-source, java-server

I've recently came across an open source library for java multithread servers http://www.quickserver.org/. The first example EchoServer which uses a ClientCommandHandler
worked perfect. However it only works with strings. In my particular application I would like to use a special custom object to exchange messages between server and client.

I tried the following:

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.quickserver.net.AppException;
import org.quickserver.net.server.DataMode;
import org.quickserver.net.server.DataType;
import org.quickserver.net.server.QuickServer;

public class TestServer {
      public static void main(String s[])  {
        QuickServer server = new QuickServer();
        try {
            server.setDefaultDataMode(DataMode.OBJECT, DataType.IN);
            server.setDefaultDataMode(DataMode.OBJECT, DataType.OUT);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        server.setClientObjectHandler("server.ObjHandler");
        server.setPort(4123);
        server.setName("EchoServer v 1.0");
        try {
          server.startServer();
        } catch(AppException e){
          System.err.println("Error in server : "+e);
        }
      }
    }
```

...and set this as an object handler...

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

import org.quickserver.net.server.ClientHandler;
import org.quickserver.net.server.ClientObjectHandler;

public class ObjHandler implements ClientObjectHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleObject(ClientHandler arg0, Object arg1)
            throws SocketTimeoutException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

So what I was trying to do with this is simply replace the command handler entirely with a object handler. I am getting the following error:

```
Loading QuickServer v2.0.0 RC1 [PID:2488]... Done
Mar 24, 2013 7:26:07 PM org.quickserver.net.server.QuickServer loadBusinessLogic
SEVERE: ClientCommandHandler AND ClientEventHandler was not set.
Mar 24, 2013 7:26:07 PM org.quickserver.net.server.QuickServer startServer
SEVERE: Exception: org.quickserver.net.AppException: ClientCommandHandler AND 
ClientEventHandler was not set.
org.quickserver.net.AppException: ClientCommandHandler AND ClientEventHandler was not set.
    at org.quickserver.net.server.QuickServer.loadBusinessLogic(QuickServer.java:3142)
    at org.quickserver.net.server.QuickServer.startServer(QuickServer.java:432)
    at server.TestServer.main(TestServer.java:24)
Error in server : org.quickserver.net.AppException: Exception :org.quickserver.net.AppException: ClientCommandHandler AND ClientEventHandler was not set.
```

So my question. Is it possible to replace the command handler with object handler without defining a command handler at all? If not what is the proper way to implement a object handler?

Answer (score 0):

It still needs the CommandHandler. But in the method "GotConnected", you can add following:

```
    public void gotConnected(ClientHandler handler) throws SocketTimeoutException,
        IOException {
    handler.setDataMode(DataMode.OBJECT, DataType.IN);
    handler.setDataMode(DataMode.OBJECT, DataType.OUT);     
}
```

and the rest of transmission will be done by your ObjectHandler class.